# Extract the line which are in comments with // aa well as /*...*/

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file and I need to extract the line which is in comments with `//` aa well as `/*...*/`as shown below:

```
//This is me
/*Multiple line arguments
best way to
use*/
Store the variables.
Swap it 

//Done
```

I tried for single line comments like this as shown below:

```
grep "//" file_name | sed 's/\/\///g'
```

Where I got my expected output for single line comments.

```
This is me
Done
```

For multi line comments `/*....*/` how to extract the lines between them to get my expected output.

Expected output:

```
This is me
Multiple line arguments
best way to
use
Done
```

Comment: What should the output be given an input line like `stuff /* foo // bar */`? Also, the answer you accepted doesn't produce the output you say you expected so its not at all clear what you were really trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` could you please try following. Written and tested as per shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{gsub(/^\/\/|^\/\*|\*\/$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Simple explanation:*** Using `gsub`(Globally substitution) function of `awk` to substitute either starting `//` OR starting `/*` OR line ending with `*/` with NULL in all the lines, then simply printing the lines.

---

***EDIT:*** In case you want to get only commented lines then following may help, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
!NF{
  next
}
/^\/\//{
  sub(/^\/\//,"")
  print
  next
}
/^\/\*/{
  sub(/^\/\*/,"")
  multiFound=1
}
/\*\/$/{
  sub(/\*\/$/,"")
  multiFound=""
  print
  next
} 
multiFound
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks, Ravinder for your quick explanation, and the above one is also working.

Comment: @Rama, your welcome Rama cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @Rama, In case you want to print only commented lines then EDIT solution should work for you too, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

To print only comments as initially requested:

```
awk '
     BEGIN { 
             prnt=0 # Initialise variable to 0
           } 
     /^\/\// { # Process lines starting with //
               $0=gensub("/","","g",$0); # Strip out every /
               print; # print the line
               next # process the next line
             } 
     /^\/\*/ { # process lines with start with /*
               prnt=1 # set the prnt variable to 1
             } 
     /^.*\*\/$/ { # Process lines that end with */
               prnt=0; # Set the prnt variable to 0
               $0=gensub("[/*]","","g",$0); # Strip / and * out of the line
               print 
             } 
     prnt==1 { 
               $0=gensub("[/*]","","g",$0); # When prnt is equal to one, strip the / and * and print
               print 
             } 
     prnt==0 {  # When prnt is 0, ignore the line and skip to the next line.
               next 
             }' file
```

One liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { prnt=0 } /^\/\// { $0=gensub("/","","g",$0);print;next } /^\/\*/ { prnt=1 } /^.*\*\/$/ { prnt=0;$0=gensub("[/*]","","g",$0);print } prnt==1 { $0=gensub("[/*]","","g",$0);;print } prnt==0 { next }' file
```

Output:

```
This is me
Multiple line arguments
best way to
use
Done
```

Awk version:

```
GNU Awk 4.0.2
```

GNU independent version using gsub as opposed to gensub:

```
awk 'BEGIN { prnt=0 } /^\/\// { gsub("/","",$0);print;next } /^\/\*/ { prnt=1 } /^.*\*\/$/ { prnt=0;gsub("[/*]","",$0);print } prnt==1 { gsub("[/*]","",$0);print } prnt==0 { next }' file
```

Comment: I tried the above code but not getting the expected output. It is retrieving the lines only from // and /*. It is not retrieving the lines between /* to */

Comment: Is it just the comments you want or all the output like the other solutions?

Comment: I need to get the lines only which are commented as expected output is shown.

Comment: Maybe your version of awk is different? I have added the version details used with the test solution.

Comment: Thanks. I've added it to the solution